# Recovering My BitCoin Core Account/Wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery

My name is Patrick and I need assistance recovering my account.  My brother sent me some bitcoin to my bitcoin core wallet.  I am unable to access this due to my laptop becoming infected with a virus and needing to be restored.  I have my wallet ID where the transaction took place, but I do not know how to access my bitcoin core wallet.  (My original laptop hard drive was fully corrupt and replaced.) I would be extremely grateful for any assistance in recovering my bitcoin core wallet.

Sincerely,
Patrick Moore

Comment: you have no backup? You don't have the wallet.dat file? What do you mean by wallet ID? the address? or the transaction number?

Comment: Correct, no backup.  The wallet.dat file was thrown away with my old harddrive.  All I have is the “string” (what I  believe is my address).  This is shown on blockchain.info.  I see my brother’s number sending it to my number.   Is there any possible way to recover it?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Access to wallets can be recovered by means of a recovery phrase, private key (string or QR code) or backup file (in this case a copy of wallet.dat).

If you have none of these you will not be able to prove ownership of the wallet and will not have access to the funds.

Comment: Thank you Jorijnsmit. How can I tell the difference between a public and private key?

Comment: a public key is derived from the private key, but you cannot go vice versa. This is due to the ECDSA logic. A private key is 32Bytes, whereas a public key in the bitcoin world is 65 Bytes long, beginning with hex "04", or as compressed keys beginning with hex "02" or "03", being 33 Bytes long.

Comment: Thank you Pebwindkraft. I have 34 characters in the Key I have here. Here are the first 10 character: “15maqpfwprkmf”. Is this a private key?

Comment: @PatrickEdwardAshodianMoore no that's an address. private keys look like this: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key#Base58_Wallet_Import_format

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use your recovery phrase ,when you open your bitcoin wallet they gave you a recovery phrase set , that is as low as 12 phrases that you should have stored on some place in order to recover your wallet in case something happens ,if you did not back up your wallet it will be difficult to recover it.

Comment: thanks Luis.  Unfortunately I didn't back up my wallet.

Comment: core doesn't provide a seed mnemonic